# No event hub namespace visible in Azure Postgresql Database Diagnostic setting

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to stream my Postgresql Logs to event hub. Whenever I open diagnostic setting I don't see 'No Namespace found' event after having Namespace created.

Attaching screenshot [image]

PS : This step exactly worked to streaming Azure Web App logs to Event hub.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue and found that the resource I was trying to add diagnostics to was in a different region than my Event Hub. I recreated the Event Hub in the same region as my resource and it showed up in the list.